# Python: Converting from ISO-8859-1/latin1 to UTF-8

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have this string that has been decoded from Quoted-printable to ISO-8859-1 with the email module. This gives me strings like "\xC4pple" which would correspond to "Äpple" (Apple in Swedish).
However, I can't convert those strings to UTF-8.

```
>>> apple = "\xC4pple"
>>> apple
'\xc4pple'
>>> apple.encode("UTF-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: ordinal not in     range(128)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Try decoding it first, then encoding:

```
apple.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8')
```

Comment: I had some problems encoding stuff to my language (Portuguese),so what worked for me was string.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('latin1'). Also, on the top of my python file, I have this # -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

Comment: Uh, `string.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('latin1')` is exactly equivalent to just `string`. (`'latin-1'` is an alias for `'iso-8859-1'`.)

Answer (score 177):

This is a common problem, so here's a relatively thorough illustration.

For non-unicode strings (i.e. those without `u` prefix like `u'\xc4pple'`), one must decode from the native encoding (`iso8859-1`/`latin1`, unless [modified with the enigmatic `sys.setdefaultencoding`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2276200/19212) function) to [`unicode`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), then encode to a character set that can display the characters you wish, in this case I'd recommend [`UTF-8`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

First, here is a handy utility function that'll help illuminate the patterns of Python 2.7 string and unicode:

```
>>> def tell_me_about(s): return (type(s), s)
```

#### A plain string

```
>>> v = "\xC4pple" # iso-8859-1 aka latin1 encoded string

>>> tell_me_about(v)
(<type 'str'>, '\xc4pple')

>>> v
'\xc4pple'        # representation in memory

>>> print v
?pple             # map the iso-8859-1 in-memory to iso-8859-1 chars
                  # note that '\xc4' has no representation in iso-8859-1, 
                  # so is printed as "?".
```

#### Decoding a iso8859-1 string - convert plain string to unicode

```
>>> uv = v.decode("iso-8859-1")
>>> uv
u'\xc4pple'       # decoding iso-8859-1 becomes unicode, in memory

>>> tell_me_about(uv)
(<type 'unicode'>, u'\xc4pple')

>>> print v.decode("iso-8859-1")
Äpple             # convert unicode to the default character set
                  # (utf-8, based on sys.stdout.encoding)

>>> v.decode('iso-8859-1') == u'\xc4pple'
True              # one could have just used a unicode representation 
                  # from the start
```

#### A little more illustration — with “Ä”

```
>>> u"Ä" == u"\xc4"
True              # the native unicode char and escaped versions are the same

>>> "Ä" == u"\xc4"  
False             # the native unicode char is '\xc3\x84' in latin1

>>> "Ä".decode('utf8') == u"\xc4"
True              # one can decode the string to get unicode

>>> "Ä" == "\xc4"
False             # the native character and the escaped string are
                  # of course not equal ('\xc3\x84' != '\xc4').
```

#### Encoding to UTF

```
>>> u8 = v.decode("iso-8859-1").encode("utf-8")
>>> u8
'\xc3\x84pple'    # convert iso-8859-1 to unicode to utf-8

>>> tell_me_about(u8)
(<type 'str'>, '\xc3\x84pple')

>>> u16 = v.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-16')
>>> tell_me_about(u16)
(<type 'str'>, '\xff\xfe\xc4\x00p\x00p\x00l\x00e\x00')

>>> tell_me_about(u8.decode('utf8'))
(<type 'unicode'>, u'\xc4pple')

>>> tell_me_about(u16.decode('utf16'))
(<type 'unicode'>, u'\xc4pple')
```

#### Relationship between unicode and UTF and latin1

```
>>> print u8
Äpple             # printing utf-8 - because of the encoding we now know
                  # how to print the characters

>>> print u8.decode('utf-8') # printing unicode
Äpple

>>> print u16     # printing 'bytes' of u16
���pple

>>> print u16.decode('utf16')
Äpple             # printing unicode

>>> v == u8
False             # v is a iso8859-1 string; u8 is a utf-8 string

>>> v.decode('iso8859-1') == u8
False             # v.decode(...) returns unicode

>>> u8.decode('utf-8') == v.decode('latin1') == u16.decode('utf-16')
True              # all decode to the same unicode memory representation
                  # (latin1 is iso-8859-1)
```

#### Unicode Exceptions

```
 >>> u8.encode('iso8859-1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0:
  ordinal not in range(128)

>>> u16.encode('iso8859-1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0:
  ordinal not in range(128)

>>> v.encode('iso8859-1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0:
  ordinal not in range(128)
```

One would get around these by converting from the specific encoding (latin-1, utf8, utf16) to unicode e.g. `u8.decode('utf8').encode('latin1')`.

So perhaps one could draw the following principles and generalizations:

- a type `str` is a set of bytes, which may have one of a number of encodings such as Latin-1, UTF-8, and UTF-16
- a type `unicode` is a set of bytes that can be converted to any number of encodings, most commonly UTF-8 and latin-1 (iso8859-1)
- the `print` command has [its own logic for encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596714), set to `sys.stdout.encoding` and defaulting to UTF-8
- One must decode a `str` to unicode before converting to another encoding.

Of course, all of this changes in Python 3.x.

Hope that is illuminating.

#### Further reading

- [Characters vs. Bytes](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2003/04/26/UTF), by Tim Bray.

And the very illustrative rants by Armin Ronacher:

- [The Updated Guide to Unicode on Python (July 2, 2013)](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/7/2/the-updated-guide-to-unicode/)
- [More About Unicode in Python 2 and 3 (January 5, 2014)](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/5/unicode-in-2-and-3/)
- [UCS vs UTF-8 as Internal String Encoding (January 9, 2014)](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/9/ucs-vs-utf8/)
- [Everything you did not want to know about Unicode in Python 3 (May 12, 2014)](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/5/12/everything-about-unicode/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed explanation, one of the best answers I ever found on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Wow. Succinct, very understandable, and explained by example.  Thanks for making the Intertubes better.

Answer (score 26):

For Python 3:

```
bytes(apple,'iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')
```

I used this for a text incorrectly encoded as iso-8859-1 (showing words like *VeÅ\x99ejnÃ©*) instead of utf-8. This code produces correct version *Veřejné*.

Comment: where does `bytes` come from?

Comment: Documentation: [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes).
Also see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3) and its answers.

Comment: For files downloaded with Requests with missing or incorrect headers: `r = requests.get(url)` and then directly setting `r.encoding = 'utf-8'` worked for me

Comment: [bytes.decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) method documentation.

Comment: It worked! Love u!

Answer (score 12):

Decode to Unicode, encode the results to UTF8.

```
apple.decode('latin1').encode('utf8')
```

Comment: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'"

Answer (score 0):

```
concept = concept.encode('ascii', 'ignore') 
concept = MySQLdb.escape_string(concept.decode('latin1').encode('utf8').rstrip())
```

I do this, I am not sure if that is a good approach but it works everytime !!