# Problematic filename - is it latin? how do i convert it to ansii?

Tags: python, string, filenames

when retrieving a file to save it from gmail, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\a.py", line 32, in on_hello
    if getmail(self):
  File "C:\a.py", line 96, in getmail
    fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: '.\\=?iso-8859-1?Q?CC_GM=5F
Est=E1vel.xlsx?='
```

Now, I suspect that `=?iso-8859-1?Q?CC_GM=5FEst=E1vel.xlsx?=` is the problem, how can I convert it to ansii? I tried using all sorts of .decode and .encode combinations with no success.

Thanks

Comment: That uses the [Encoded-Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) encoding. This encoding has no business existing anywhere *except* in MIME Headers.

Comment: Did you mean: "ansi" or "ascii"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at a [Quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding (a variant as used in MIME email headers, called [encoded-word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word)). The [`email.header` module](http://docs.python.org/library/email.header.html) handles this for you:

```
>>> from email.header import decode_header
>>> for part in decode_header('=?iso-8859-1?Q?CC_GM=5FEst=E1vel.xlsx?='):
...     value = str(*part)
...     print(value)
...
CC GM_Estável.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a MIME-encoded email header.

You should* be able to use something in here, perhaps `decode`:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header.html

*I don't regularly write Python; your mileage  may vary.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, iso-8859-1 has a number of characters that ansi does not have [see this](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/charsetdiffs.html#c). Are you sure that you can safely ignore all those characters in your situation? One other idea which I would tend more towards would be an iso-8859-1, to (some flavour of Unicode, i.e. utf8, utf16, etc). Here is an answer to your question from [SO] which will do the conversion[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539881/python-converting-from-iso-8859-1-latin1-to-utf-8).
CHEERS!