# Python3 encode unicode

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encoding, python-requests

When I do get request with requests lib in Python3 I get this response:

> {"status":true,"data":[{"koatuu":7121586600,"zona":8,"kvartal":2,"parcel":501,"cadnum":"7121586600:08:002:0501","ownershipcode":100,"purpose":"\u0414\u043b\u044f \u0432\u0435\u0434\u0435\u043d\u043d\u044f \u0442\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0440\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0441\u0456\u043b\u044c\u0441\u044c\u043a\u043e\u0433\u043e\u0441\u043f\u043e\u0434\u0430\u0440\u0441\u044c\u043a\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0432\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0431\u043d\u0438\u0446\u0442\u0432\u0430","use":"\u0414\u043b\u044f \u0432\u0435\u0434\u0435\u043d\u043d\u044f \u0442\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0440\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0441\u0456\u043b\u044c\u0441\u044c\u043a\u043e\u0433\u043e\u0441\u043f\u043e\u0434\u0430\u0440\u0441\u044c\u043a\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0432\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0431\u043d\u0438\u0446\u0442\u0432\u0430","area":"1.3397","unit_area":"\u0433\u0430                       ","ownershipvalue":null,"id_office":630}]}

How can I get cp1252 letters as response?

My code is:

```
import requests
url = 'http://map.land.gov.ua/kadastrova-karta/get-parcel-Info?koatuu=7121586600&zone=08&quartal=002&parcel=0004'
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.text)
```

Comment: I'd convert the response locally. JSON is typically UTF-8 encoded and you're probably not going to get a third party service to change their encoding for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539881/python-converting-from-iso-8859-1-latin1-to-utf-8

Comment: At python3 encode.decode does not work.

Comment: I don't know Python, but according to [this](http://pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/) `<string>.encode()` and `.decode()` still seem to be the way to go?

Comment: If that doesn't work out, I would suggest changing the question title to something like `How to convert UTF-8 string to cp1252 in Python 3` and editing the question to describe how encode/decode don't work for you.

Comment: The title is right. Im looking for encoding solution for Python3.

Comment: OK, if you think that's a clearer title....

Comment: What exactly are "cp1252 letters"…?

Answer (score 0):

```
print(page.json())
```

solved my problem :D