# noob queries on unicode and str methods in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I wish to seek some clarifications on Unicode and str methods in Python. After reading some [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596714/why-does-python-print-unicode-characters-when-the-default-encoding-is-ascii) on Unicode, there are still couple of doubts I hope folks can help me on:

1. Am I right to say that when declaring a unicode string e.g `word=u'foo'`, python uses the encoding of the terminal and decodes `foo` in e.g `UTF-8`, and assigning `word` the hex representation in unicode?
2. So, in general, is the process of printing out characters in a file, always decoding the byte stream according to the encoding to unicode representation, before displaying the mapped characters out?
3. In my terminal, Why does `'é'.lower()` or `str('é')` displays in hex `'\xc3\xa9'`, whereas 'a'.lower() does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we should be clear we are talking about Python 2 only. Python 3 is different.

1. You're right. But if you write u"abcd" in a py file, the declaration of the encoding of the source file will determine how the interpreter decode you string.
2. You need to decode it first, and then encode it and print. In Python 2, DON'T print out unicode directly! Otherwise, if the system is encoding it in an incompatitable way (like "ascii"), an exception will be raised.
   You have to do all these explicitly.
3. The short answer is "a" doesn't have to be represented in "\x61", "a" is simply more readable. A longer answer: typically in the interactive shell, if you type a value and press enter, Python will show the repr() of your string. I think "repr" will try to print everything in ascii representation. For "a", it's already ascii, so it's outputed directly. For str "é", it's UTF-8 encoded binary stream, so Python escape each byte and print as 'xc3\xa9'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Python does any automatic encoding or decoding on console I/O. Consider the following:

```
>>> 'é'
'\xc3\xa9'
>>> 'é'.decode('UTF-8')
u'\xe9'
```

You'll notice that `\xe9` is the Unicode code point for ['LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm), while `\xc3\xa9` is the byte sequence corresponding to the same character in UTF-8.

Everything changes in Python 3, since all strings are Unicode. I'm not sure of the rules there.

Comment: re “automatic encoding/decoding”: check `sys.stdin.encoding` and `sys.stdout.encoding`.

Answer (score 0):

1. See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ about how to specify encoding of Python source file. For Python interpreter there's PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable.
2. What OS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

1. The statement `word = u'foo'` assigns a unicode string *object*, not a "hex representation". Unicode objects represent sequences of text characters. Also, it is wrong to think of *decoding* in this context. Unicode is *not* an encoding, nor does it "have" an encoding.
2. Yes. Decode In: Encode Out.
3. For the `repr` of a *non-unicode* string literal, Python will use `sys.stdin.encoding`; for the `repr` of a *unicode* string literal, Python will use "unicode_escape".