# why are strings encoded in utf-8 if the default encoding is ascii? - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

In python, when I `import sys` and type:

```
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
>>> 'ascii'
```

why is this string automatically encoded as UTF-8?

```
>>> a = 'ö'
>>> a
>>> '\xc3\xb6'
```

Comment: Using [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit)?

Comment: No, I'm still using Python 2.7

Comment: I think [this][1] comes close to what I was looking for.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596714/why-does-python-print-unicode-characters-when-the-default-encoding-is-ascii

Answer (score 1):

Because the input you provided to python was

```
 a        =       '   ö       '
\x61\x20\x3d\x20\x27\xc3\xb6\x27
```

You told `a` to contain the byte sequence `"\xc3\xb6"` by putting those two bytes between the quotes in your console input, and so it does.

Comment: But why doesn't it use ascii instead since it is the default encoding and I haven't defined any other encoding?

Comment: @user2635863: Because there's isn't any ascii encoding for `ö`.

Comment: @user2635863 because we're not encoding anything. And what would it mean for it to "use ascii" anyway?

Comment: @martineau: yes, then I'd have expected an error since there's no ascii encoding for ö. Does this mean that the python interpreter encodes strings automatically to utf-8 (in case of non-ascii characters) even though the default system encoding is ascii?

Comment: @user2635863: On my system, `>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()` also returns `'ascii'`, but after `>>> a = 'ö'`, `>>> a` displays `'\x94'`, not `'\xc3\xb6'`. Also `>>> a.encode('utf-8')` and `>>> 'ö'.encode('utf-8')` both result in `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Comment: This is a function of your *terminal*, not of Python.