# latin-1 vs unicode in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, latin1

I was reading this [high rated post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596714/why-does-python-print-unicode-characters-when-the-default-encoding-is-ascii?rq=1) in SO on `unicodes`

Here is an `illustration given there :

```
$ python

>>> import sys

>>> print sys.stdout.encoding
UTF-8

>>> print '\xe9' # (1)
é
>>> print u'\xe9' # (2)
Ã©
>>> print u'\xe9'.encode('latin-1') # (3)
é
>>>
```

and the explanation were given as

> (1) python outputs binary string as is, terminal receives it and tries to match its value with latin-1 character map. In latin-1, 0xe9 or 233 yields the character "é" and so that's what the terminal displays.

My question is: why does the terminal match to the latin-1 character map when the `encoding` is `'UTF-8'`?

Also when I tried

```
>>> print '\xe9'
?
>>> print u'\xe9'
é
```

I get different result for the first one than what is described above. why is this discrepancy and where does `latin-1` come to play in this picture?

Comment: I'm not sure how the OP managed to get that output, but that is *incorrect*, unless the OP *changed* the `sys.stdout.encoding` value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing some important context; in that case the OP configured the terminal emulator (Gnome Terminal) to interpret output as Latin-1 but left the shell variables set to UTF-8. Python thus is told by the shell to use UTF-8 for Unicode output but the actual configuration of the terminal is to expect Latin-1 bytes.

The `print` output clearly shows the terminal is interpreting output using Latin-1, and is *not* using UTF-8.

When a terminal is set to UTF-8, the `\xe9` byte is not valid (incomplete) UTF-8 and your terminal *usually* prints a question mark instead:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'
>>> print '\xe9'
?
>>> print u'\xe9'
é
>>> print u'\xe9'.encode('utf8')
é
```

If you instruct Python to ignore such errors, it gives you the U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER glyph `�` instead:

```
>>> '\xe9'.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: unexpected end of data
>>> '\xe9'.decode('utf8', 'replace')
u'\ufffd'
>>> print '\xe9'.decode('utf8', 'replace')
�
```

That's because in UTF-8, `\xe9` is the start byte of a 3-byte encoding, for the Unicode codepoints U+9000 through to U+9FFF, and if printed as just a single byte is invalid. This works:

```
>>> print '\xe9\x80\x80'
退
```

because that's the UTF-8 encoding of the U+9000 codepoint, a CJK Ideograph glyph.

If you want to understand the difference between encodings and Unicode, and how UTF-8 and other codecs work, I strongly recommend you read:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Comment: so why is that `'xe9'` and `u'\xe9` prints different and the difference between `latin-1` and `unicode`, since one of them uses one byte and other two?? (my vague understanding from that post)

Comment: I was under the impression that `?` is the unicode representation but not for a invalid `UTF-8`,that brings to the question of how `?` is represented in `UTF-8`. On the same note, `print chr(0xFF)` prints `?`

Comment: @user1988876: `?` is just `U+003F`, or `\x3f` as a UTF-8, Latin1 or ASCII byte.

Comment: @user1988876: *any* single byte outside the range 00-7F is invalid in UTF-8. After U+007F all codepoints require at least 2 bytes to encode.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for the pointing out. so would that mean it is valid in `UTF-16`?

Comment: @user1988876: no, UTF-16 always uses multiples of *two* bytes. For most of the Unicode standard, one such pair is enough, beyond U+FFFF two pairs are used.

Comment: `\xe9` - how do you say that this the start byte of 3-byte encoding. any table look up? or some calculation - sorry if this sounds stupid

Comment: @eagertoLearn: see the [Wikipedia article on UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8); UTF-8 is a variable-byte encoding.

Comment: @eagertoLearn: If you look at the binary representation of hex E9, you'll see it starts with 3 bits set, one bit not set (`1110 1001`); this indicates it's the starting byte of a 3-byte character. A single-byte sequence starts with `0` (values 00-7F), a two-byte sequence stats with `110` (values C0-DF), 3 bytes with `1110` (E0-EF), etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I understand `E9` is `1110 1001`, but I do not see how it starts with a 3 `bits set` with one bit not being set.

Comment: @eagertoLearn: `1110` is three set bits (each 1), and a 0 (not set).

Comment: @MartijnPieters:huh! I see what you mean, but how does that indicate its gthe starting  byte of a 3-byte character. this is the confusing part. rest of your explanation is very clear. Thanks again

Comment: That's how the standard was designed; it makes the work of decoders easier.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: can you give me an example of 3-byte character. I added `F` to make it three byte (`chr(0xE9F)`) but I get  `Value error`

Comment: @eagertoLearn: There is such a character in the answer. You want a *unicode* codepoint (`unichr()` perhaps) or produce *3 bytes*, where `chr()` can only produce **one** byte. `chr(0xE9) + chr(0x80) + chr(0x80)` for example.