# Python Shell not running Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am running Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit to use Scrapy. I have some code that is working when I run it via Command Shell (apart from some issues with Command Shell not recognising non Unicode characters), however when I try running the script via the Python IDLE i get the following error message:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\mrscrap\mrscrap\spiders\test.py", line 24
    class MySpider(BaseSpider):
ScrapyDeprecationWarning: __main__.MySpider inherits from deprecated class scrapy.spider.BaseSpider, please inherit from scrapy.spider.Spider. (warning only on first subclass, there may be others)
```

The code used to generate this error is:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
import re

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "wiki"
    allowed_domains = ["wikipedia.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia"]

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.selector.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
        for titles in titles:

            body = response.xpath("//p").extract()
            body2 = "".join(body)
            print remove_tags(body2)
```

Firstly, what is the cause of this error when it works fine in Command Shell? Secondly, when I follow the instructions in the error and replace both instances of BaseSpider within the code with just 'Spider' the code runs in Python shell, but does nothing. No error, nothing printed to the log, no errors or warnings, nothing.

Can anyone tell me why this revised version of the code is not printing it's output to the Python IDLE?

Thanks

Comment: instead of from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider do `from scrapy.spider import Spider`

Comment: @Jordan i have already done that. when i do it no longer errors, but just doesnt do anything.

Comment: is this all your code?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham hello again. yes it is...i had a more complicated version of this code that i've been able to par back thanks to the help of other users. when i run it in command shell i get just the text output i want. i've tested on bbc sport and wiki so far. in python IDLE i get an error with basespider and nothing at all using just spider.

Comment: so just in idle you are having the issue? How are you running it in idle?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes runs fine now in command shell...i dont really want to be running it via that method though. i want to replace my current 'scrapy crawl myproject' in command shell with just hitting F5 in IDLE like i do with everything else.

Comment: @user3045351, I added an answer that should work, you need to call scrapy crawl on your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `from scrapy.cmdline import execute` to your imports

Then put `execute(['scrapy','crawl','wiki'])` and run your script.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
import re
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "wiki"
    allowed_domains = ["wikipedia.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia"]

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.selector.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
        for title in titles:

            body = response.xpath("//p").extract()
            body2 = "".join(body)
            print remove_tags(body2)

execute(['scrapy','crawl','wiki'])
```

Comment: type into python shell you mean? that generated the error 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    execute (['scrapy', 'crawl', 'wiki'])
NameError: name 'execute' is not defined'

Comment: import from scrapy.cmdline import execute first, add the import to top of your script and the execute command at the bottom then hit f5

Comment: ok, i added import at the top of the script and the execute line right at the bottom, below the print statement. the code did not error, but again it just did nothing.

Comment: choose `run module`, you will be asked to save the file first if you have not already

Comment: ...yeah thats what i did Run Module - F5

Comment: you saved it and ran it using run module and your code looks like the code I added?

Comment: Sorry, fell asleep!yes, added import statement to top of code, execute statement, indented and as the last line, the saved, the pressed 'Run Module -F5'. Code seems to run through and complete, but nothing prints to the IDLE...

Comment: resolved...it was late and i didnt notice the last line of the code was not indented.

Comment: I was just about to reply and ask you that very question, glad it is sorted.

Comment: thanks for all your help again. im slowly starting to get there now. im going to do a bit more testing on individual web pages just to see if the code I have wont scrape any for any reason, then start looking to build code that can scrape multiple web pages and obtain data from tables within websites. im interested in sports and stock market data to begin with.

Comment: You're welcome. Scrapy is a great tool, you should be able to do what you want no problem.