# Python - how to fix utf8 to stdout without buffering

Tags: python, unicode, stdout

In python3, I have had problems printing unicode characters to stdout, with the script failing, until I set this at the top of the file:

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout.buffer)
```

but this then buffers the output, and I'd like to see the output as it is generated, line-by-line. What should I alter to stop the buffering?

Comment: Back up a step - how are you printing to stdout? Using normal `print` I hope?

Comment: yes, just normal print(). I think the problem is that I can't set the locale in the terminal I'm using, but the line above seems to fix that.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: There is some Python2 vs. Python3 difference, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374455/how-to-set-sys-stdout-encoding-in-python-3

Comment: @RemyJ it works on OS X, but not on FreeBSD, FWIW

Comment: According to [mike](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21968640/6683985) it seems that the characters that Python can print are bound to the environment from which it was initiated...