# len(unicode string)

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

```
>>> c='中文'
>>> c
'\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87'
>>> len(c)
6
>>> cu=u'中文'
>>> cu
u'\u4e2d\u6587'
>>> len(cu)
2
>>> s=''
>>> s
'\xf0\xa4\xad\xa2'
>>> len(s)
4
>>> su=u''
>>> su
u'\U00024b62'
>>> len(su)
2
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'
```

First, I want to make some concepts clear myself.
I've learned that unicode string like `cu=u'中文'` ,actually is encoded in UTF-16 by python shell default. Right? **So, when we saw `'\u*'` , that actually `UTF-16 encoding`? And `'\u4e2d\u6587'` is an unicode string or byte string?** But `cu` has to be stored in the memory, so

```
0100 1110 0010 1101 0110 0101 1000 0111
```

(convert \u4e2d\u6587 to binary) is the form that `cu` preserved if that a byte string? **Am I right?**

But it can't be byte string. Otherwise len(cu) can't be 2, it should be 4!!
So it has to be unicode string. **BUT!!!** I've also [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596714/why-does-python-print-unicode-characters-when-the-default-encoding-is-ascii/21968640#21968640) that

> python attempts to implicitly encode the Unicode string with whatever
>   scheme is currently set in sys.stdout.encoding, in this instance it's
>   "UTF-8".

```
>>> cu.encode('utf-8')
'\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87'
```

So! how could `len(cu)` == 2??? Is that because there are two `'\u'` in it?

But that doesn't make `len(su) == 2` sense!

Am I missing something?

I'm using python 2.7.12

Comment: characters != bytes. a utf16 character is 2 bytes, but only one character.

Comment: You want to read up about Unicode *first*. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! that's very helpful

Comment: @MarcB Could you give more detail?

Comment: @MarcB So , len(ob) is not just return how many bytes ob are or what?

Answer (score 0):

The Python `unicode` type holds *Unicode codepoints*, and is not meant to be an encoding. How Python does this internally is an implementation detail and not something you need to be concerned with most of the time. They are not UTF-16 code units, because UTF-16 is another codec you can use to encode Unicode text, just like UTF-8 is.

The most important thing here is that a standard Python `str` object holds *bytes*, which may or may not hold text encoded to a certain codec (your sample uses UTF-8 but that's not a given), and `unicode` holds *Unicode codepoints*. In an interactive interpreter session, it is the codec of your terminal that determines what bytes are received by Python (which then uses `sys.stdin.encoding` to decode these as needed when you create a `u'...'` `unicode` object).

Only when *writing to `sys.stdout`* (say, when using `print`) does the `sys.stdout.encoding` value come to play, where Python will automatically encode your Unicode strings again. Only *then* will your 2 Unicode codepoints be encoded to UTF-8 again and written to your terminal, which knows how to interpret those.

You probably want to read up about Python and Unicode, I recommend:

- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Come up another question. As you mentioned, only when use `print` , python will automatically encode unicode string again. So the bash shell will decode it again to unicode when receive it in order to display on the screen and use that unicode to match something so-called rendered or something I'm not sure, or just leave it to glyph. So Can I simply think that if I want display something on screen, Unicode is the last form ? Uh, can you get my point?