# Why running a python script is not the same as running individual commands?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, string-formatting

I have been having lots of trouble with encondings in python. While searching the net for answers, I have come upon many replies, but none of them actually worked. Then, I found out this behaviour: running the commands in the python interpreter behaves different from actually running the script. See:

```
$ cat prueba.py 
print("{} con leche".format('Café'))

$ python prueba.py 
  File "prueba.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file prueba.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

$ python
Python 2.7.12+ (default, Sep  1 2016, 20:27:38) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160927] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("{} con leche".format('Café'))
Café con leche
>>>
```

Can anyone explain this to me? (and, if possible, also help me with the encoding problem)

Comment: Did you follow the link in the error message, which explains it fully?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Python print unicode characters when the default encoding is ASCII?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596714/why-does-python-print-unicode-characters-when-the-default-encoding-is-ascii)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must add encoding in your script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print("{} con leche".format('Café'))
```