# How to fix Python encoding in terminal

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

How do you set the default encoding Python uses with `sys.stdout` when run from a terminal program like Gnome-Terminal?

If I execute a Python script inside Gnome-Terminal, I get the notorious "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character" error if the script tries to print unicode characters. However, even though Gnome-Terminal's encoding is set to "UTF-8", if I print `sys.stdout.encoding` it shows "ANSI_X3.4-1968".

Minimal code to reproduce the error is:

```
python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding; print u"\u0411\n"'
```

Why isn't Python using the terminal's encoding of utf-8?

Note, I'm *not* asking how to convert my string to ASCII.

Comment: what does `echo $LANG` and `echo $LC_ALL` print?

Comment: Tried `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your script file ?

Comment: @Szabolcs There's no script, as far as I understood -- just one command.

Comment: Can you show output of `locale` command in your terminal, please?

Comment: What if you encode the unicode string using a suitable encoding like `utf8` before printing it?

Comment: Not quite the answer to your problem, but the info here might help you figure it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596714/why-does-python-print-unicode-characters-when-the-default-encoding-is-ascii

Comment: @Szabolcs and the upvoters.  `# coding: utf8` declares the encoding of the *source file* and *nothing else*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) variable, or using the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374455/how-to-set-sys-stdout-encoding-in-python-3#4374457).